# Menu opens and fades away when actionBar is set to hide();

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

How can I make sure the ICS options menu still opens without using the actionbar? If I dont have an action bar, the old style shows while opening the menu button.
If i include the ActionBar but hide it, the menu opens and fades away instantly when menu is  clicked. What can I do?